# Unit Testing Doctrine 2 Models

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit, zend-test

Whats the way to unit test Doctrine 2 models? I am using it with Zend Framework 1.11. It has `Zend_Test` which uses PHPUnit. I think the right thing to use is [`PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/database.html). In Zend Framework, I can use [`Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.db.html). How can I modify the code to unit test Doctrine Models instead of `Zend_Db` classes.

1st, I think instead of using `Zend_Db` stuff, I have to use Doctrine's stuff instead

```
class BugsTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase
{
    private $_connectionMock;

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        if($this->_connectionMock == null) {
            $connection = Zend_Db::factory(...);
            $this->_connectionMock = $this->createZendDbConnection(
                $connection, 'zfunittests'
            );
            Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($connection);
        }
        return $this->_connectionMock;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [`DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) that has extensions for PHPUnit via `ORMTestCase`. Usage looks something like

```
namespace MyProject\Tests;

use DoctrineExtensions\PHPUnit\OrmTestCase

class EntityFunctionalTest extends OrmTestCase
{
    protected function createEntityManager()
    {
        return Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(..);
    }

    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createFlatXmlDataSet(__DIR__."/_files/entityFixture.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you want to test? If its just the model per se - thats not too difficult. Doctrine 2 models are just plain PHP objects with annotations containing the mapping information. Thats the good thing about Doctrine 2 being "persinstance ignorant": you can test the models just like any regular class.